# TexShop Add Period with Double-Space

Tags: texshop, macos

When I switched to MacOS Ventura awhile back, I noticed the OS started adding a period after a double-space.  I turned this off in Keyboard -> Input Sources -> Add period with a double-space, and it's worked for everything *except* TexShop, which still adds the period.

I thought this would get fixed in an update, but it seems to be hanging on, so I'm wondering if it's just me.  Is there something more I need to do to turn it off for TexShop?

Comment: Not happening to me.